# How to get the html source of a page in Qt 5.4 - qwebengine

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.4, qtwebengine

I’m trying to retrieve the source of a page in the new qwebengine(Qt5.4) but I don’t know what I’m doing wrong:

```
 QString html;
 this->page()->toHtml([&html](const QString &result){ html = result; });

 qDebug() << html; // is still empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step of printf-debugging this would be to check if the lambda is ever called: `{ qDebug() << "Lambda:" << result; html = result; }`. Code looks fine to me.

Make sure, however, that you do not call `toHtml` before the `loadFinished` was emitted. This might cause it to fail.

Please note that `toHtml` operates asynchronously. If you print the contents of `html` right after the `toHtml` call the callback will not have been called yet.

I suggest adding a custom signal to your class that is emitted by the callback when the HTML is available.

Alternatively, do whatever you want to do with the HTML code directly in the callback.

Comment: Are you aware that the call is asynchronous, that is, if you do a qDebug() right after toHtml that then the callback will not have been called yet?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what are you saying?

Comment: I mean that when toHtml returns the result is not there yet. You have to wait until the callback gets called. My suggestion here is to use a signal emitted by the callback.